# Cannot call non-static method statically

Tags: php, static, non-static

I have recently done an update to PHP 8.3, and I get an error about static and non-static code. Non-static method ::prepare_output_from_query() cannot be called statically in line 68

```
Line 68

$order_items = self::prepare_output_from_query( $order_items ) ;
```

Thank you!

I researched other similar issues posted online and think i have found solution about calling it (New Self) but wanted to confirm with others before implementing change.

Comment: Have you tried: `$order_items = $this->prepare_output_from_query($order_items)`?

Comment: Just make your function `static` or use it as KIKO mentioned